# Integrating after using integrating factor

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I have a question here $x\frac{dy}{dx}-2y=x^4\sin(x)$. I rearranged it to $\frac{dy}{dx}-\frac{2y}{x}=x^3\sin(x)$

I need to find a general solution to this. I used the integrating factor method and know the integrating factor is $e^{\int\frac{2}{x}dx}$which is $e^{2\ln|x|}$. I multiplied everything by the integrating factor. The equation becomes $\frac{dy}{dx}2\ln|x|-\frac{2y}{x}\ln|x|y=x^3\sin(x)2\ln|x|$

Question. How do I integrate and find the general solution from here? General solution = having $y=....$. So clearly I need to integrate. How do I arrange this in a way so I can integrate it? And what is the final answer?

Comment: Note that  $e^{2\ln x}=x^2$. This is your integrating factor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$x\frac{dy}{dx}-2y=x^4\sin(x)$$
$$x^2\frac{dy}{dx}-2xy=x^5\sin(x)$$
$$\dfrac {x^2\frac{dy}{dx}-2xy}{x^4}=x\sin(x)$$
$$\left(\dfrac  {y} {x^2} \right)'=x\sin(x)$$
Then integrate both sides.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
$$\frac{dy}{dx}+P(x)y=Q(x) \implies I(x)=e^{\int P(x) dx}$$
Then $$y(x)=I^{-1}(x)\int Q(x) I(x) dx+c I^{-1}(x)$$